# System.ArgumentException: 'Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.' C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, sql, windows-forms-designer

So I'm trying to take combobox and textbox input values from the current form and add them to a listbox on the following form. However I get the following error

[System.ArgumentException: 'Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTz3X.jpg)

I've tried to make the datasource = null 'listbox1.DataSource = null;' and clear the listbox contents 'listbox1.Items.Clear();'. However, when I proceed to the next form the to see the saved values, the values are invisible in the listbox. However, all of the inputs are saved to the sql database.

[Modified Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQzDs.jpg)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVB0D.jpg)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

[Code Block related to the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y06IP.jpg)

@aepot
I have followed your code example and still seem to get the empty listbox. Also, if I use AccountInfo which is my property class instead of string then the exception from before comes back. I'm not sure what else can be done at this point.
[AccountInfo Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0JqC.jpg)
Adjusting
[Comparisson](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfkyR.jpg)
Result
[Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdYDK.jpg)

@aepot
Here is the code if you're still interested in helping
DataAccess Class

```
public void InsertNewCardDetails(string card_Type, string card_Number, string expiry_date, string _ccv, string _duration)
        {
            using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\nauri\source\repos\StylistsApp\Database\UserAccountDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"))
            {
                List<AccountInfo> accounts = new List<AccountInfo>();
                accounts.Add(new AccountInfo {cardType = card_Type, cardNumber = card_Number, expiryDate = expiry_date, ccv = _ccv, duration = _duration });
                connection.Execute("INSERT INTO[Table] (cardType, cardNumber, expiryDate, ccv, duration) VALUES(@cardType, @cardNumber, @expiryDate, @ccv, @duration)", accounts);
            }
                 
        }
```

Here I'm just binding variables to input fields

```
  public partial class CardDetails : Form
    {
        public CardDetails()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            DataAccess db = new DataAccess();
            SetValueForCardType = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(); 
            SetValueForCardNumber = textBox5.Text;
            SetValueForExpiryDate = textBox2.Text;
            SetValueForCCV = textBox3.Text;
            SetValueForDuration = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
            db.InsertNewCardDetails(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(), textBox5.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text, comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString());
            //MessageBox.Show("Account Created Successfully!");

            this.Close();
            Summary summary = new Summary();
            summary.Show();

        }
    

    
        public static string SetValueForCardType = "";
        public static string SetValueForCardNumber = "";
        public static string SetValueForExpiryDate = "";
        public static string SetValueForCCV = "";
        public static string SetValueForDuration = "";
```

Here I'm trying to retrieve info from the previous form

```
 public partial class Summary : Form
    {
        //List<AccountInfo> people = new List<AccountInfo>();
        private BindingList<string> items = new BindingList<string>();
        public Summary()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Summary_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            listBox1.DataSource = items;
        }
        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\nauri\source\repos\StylistsApp\Database\UserAccountDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
            sql.Open();                                      
            SqlCommand sqa = new SqlCommand("Select cardType, cardNumber, expiryDate, ccv, duration from [Table] where email =@email", sql);
            sqa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Form1.SetValueForText1);
            SqlDataReader da = sqa.ExecuteReader();
            while (da.Read())
            {
                items.Add("Hello");
                items.Add("World");
                items.Add(da.GetValue(2).ToString());
                items.Add(da.GetValue(3).ToString());
                items.Add(da.GetValue(4).ToString());

            }
            sql.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Screenshots of code are not helpful. Please post the code as a code block

Comment: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186/756067)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `BindingList<T>` as `DataSource`

```csharp
private BindingList<string> items = new BindingList<string>();
```

Then assign the `DataSource`

```csharp
listBox1.DataSource = items;
```

Then you can modify the Collection fluently

```csharp
items.Add("Hello");
items.Add("World");
```

or

```csharp
items.Clear();
```

`ListBox` will update its layout automatically.

Note: if you'll reassign `new BindingList` instance to `items` during the app execution, don't forget to reassign the `DataSource` then.

The same can be applied to any `Control` which has `DataSource`.

---

**Edit**

> however, now when I enter the values to be displayed in listbox1, the listbox is blank but you can see the blue selected fields for each line in the listbox where text should appear

Cannot reproduce that. See the following code. To reproduce it in Designer I've just added a `ListBox` and a `Button` without any additional setup.

```csharp
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private BindingList<string> items = new BindingList<string>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.DataSource = items;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        items.Add("Hello");
        items.Add("World");
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I no longer get the exception, however, now when I enter the values to be displayed in listbox1, the listbox is blank but you can see the blue selected fields for each line in the listbox where text should appear.

Comment: @NaurisBr what if you replace `da.GetValue(x).ToString()` with some explicit string? Just for test. And please don't ignore the suggestion to insert the code as text instead of screenshots. You're violating StackOverflow guidelines.

Comment: @NaurisBr please follow the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Well, apologies. I'm new to asking questions on stack overflow. I tried inserting it that way but it kept telling me it was in the incorrect format. And no, it still doesn't work but I appreciate your efforts :)

Comment: @NaurisBr If you change `items.Add(da.GetValue(0).ToString())` to `items.Add("Some text")`, are you really getting `incorrect format`? I'm surprised. I can't help you because i simply don't want to type your code from image to my Visual Studio. But the issue in the SQL

Comment: I was surprised too when it didn't work after explicitly typing a string. At least now I know that the issue is with my SQL config code and not the summary_load method. If you have the time, I have added all of my code in text format. I can understand if you don't want to help anymore.

Comment: @NaurisBr i have no solution at the moment but you may try something like `items.Add(da.GetString(0))`, etc. regarding to data type. And simplify the query as `SELECT cardNumber FROM ...`. Also it would be nice to know what line of code produces the Exception. The best way (as for me) to debug something is making it as simple as possible.

Comment: @NaurisBr btw, the question about the issue with `DataSource` is solved. You make mark this answer as accepted and create another question about ADO.NET if nothing helps.

Comment: Cheers. I actually figured out the problem anyways so it is solved. The issue was with duplicate columns in my SQL dataset trying to overwrite one another.